# Code in the web part

Tags: web-part

I have the following code in a web part which does the job to pull the information from the external website and create an XML file as data source to a datalist web control. This Data list should be displayed in the webpart. For some reason, I can not see any information if I use this in the web part. Please guide me how to fix this problem.

```
string sJobURL = "http://www.example.com/extsearch/?client_id=123034&infonly=1&quick_search=0&show_desc=Y";
        string sInternalJobURL = "http://www.example.com/extsearch/?client_id=123034&infonly=1&quick_search=0&show_desc=Y";
        string sJobsPath = @"C:\app\jobs.xml";
        string sInternalJobsPath = @"C:\app\internaljobs.xml";
        string sProcessed = @"C:\app\Alljobs.xml";
        string sRootElementName = "vacancy_details";
        string sUniqueKeyName = "id";

        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(ReadRequest(sJobURL));
        xml.Save(sJobsPath);

        xml.LoadXml(ReadRequest(sInternalJobURL));
        xml.Save(sInternalJobsPath);

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(sJobsPath);
        var result = doc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName(sRootElementName)[0] as XmlElement;
        Merge(sInternalJobsPath, doc, result, sProcessed, sRootElementName);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(sProcessed);
        var query = xdoc.Descendants(sRootElementName).Select(data => data.Element(sUniqueKeyName).Value).Distinct();
        xdoc.Save(sProcessed);
        RemoveDTDFromXML(sProcessed);
        ds.ReadXml(sProcessed);

        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            datalist.DataSource = ds.Tables[sRootElementName].DefaultView;
            datalist.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Version of SharePoint? Is this a visual web part? Try running debugger and confirm your ds.tables.count is in fact greater than 0.

Comment: it is sharepoint 2010 and it is a visual web part. I am not sure if I can run this code as it is. I have not created any Sharepoint list by using BCS.

Comment: Where is this code? OnLoad? PreRender? OnInit?

Comment: You shouldn't need BCS, as you're calling a service directly in code.

Comment: I am using this code in oninit.